# How to show the comments which belongs to the post?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I'm creating a news feed kind of thing where users can post anything and the post will have comments also. I'm able to create the newsfeed and the comment section, but my real problem is I'm not able to show the comments which belongs to the post. Right now all the comments are displayed under every news feed. Though I've declared the eloquent relationship between feed and comment but still I'm not able to save the feed_id in comment table.

```
This is my FeedsController:-
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;
use Auth;
use Sentinel;
use App\Feed;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Blog;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Comment;

class FeedsController extends Controller
{
public function index() {

  $comments = Comment::latest()->get();
  $feeds = Feed::where('user_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->latest()->get(); 
  $blogs = Blog::latest()->simplePaginate(5);
  $blogs->setPath('blog');
  return view('action.index')->with('feeds', $feeds)->with('comments', $comments)->with('blogs', $blogs);
}

public function store(Requests\CreateFeedRequest $request){
    $requet = $request->all();
    $request['user_id'] = Sentinel::getuser()->id;

  Feed::create($request->all());


  return redirect('home');
}

 public function storecomment(Requests\CommentRequest $request, Feed $feed)
 {

$comment = new Comment;
$comment->user_id =Sentinel::getuser()->id;
$comment->feed_id = $request->feed_id;
$comment->comment = $request->comment;
$comment->save();
  return redirect('home');
}  
}
```

This is the models:
    Comment model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
 'comment',
 'user_id',
 'feed_id'
 ];

 public function feed()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Feed');
 }

 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
 }
```

Feed model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feed extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
 'feed_id',
 'user_id',
 'feed_content'
 ];

 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }

 public function comment()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
 }
}
```

User model:-

```
<?php namespace App;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class User extends EloquentUser {


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes to be fillable from the model.
 *
 * A dirty hack to allow fields to be fillable by calling empty fillable array
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [];
protected $guarded = ['id'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

/**
* To allow soft deletes
*/
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



public function feeds() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Feed');
}

public function comment()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
 }
 }
```

This is my feed.blade.php where I'm displaying the feeds output and commnets

```
@foreach($feeds as $feed)
<article class="media">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="pull-left"> 
            <img class="profile" src="{{ URL::to('/uploads/users/'.$feed->user->pic)  }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" style="width:48px;height:48px;padding-right : 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;">
         </div>
        <strong>{{ $feed->user->first_name }} 
                {{ $feed->user->last_name }}
                <small> posted </small>
         </strong>
                {{ $feed->created_at->diffForHumans() }}<br><hr>
                {{ $feed->feed_content }}

            <hr>
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'home/{storecomment}']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::text('comment', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows'=>3, 'placeholder'=>"Comment"]) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group feed_post_submit">
                    <a href="/home">{!! Form::submit('Comment', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-xs']) !!}</a>
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}

            @foreach($comments as $comment)
                <div class="pull-left"> 
                    <img class="profile" src="{{ URL::to('/uploads/users/'. $comment->user->pic)  }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" style="width:48px;height:48px;padding-right : 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                </div>
                {{ $comment->user->first_name }} 
                {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                {{ $comment->comment }}<hr>
            @endforeach
    </div>
</article>
@endforeach
```

Can anyone tell me how to store the feed_id into comment table and displaying the comments according to the feed. Thank You. I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: You can use Laravel's models. This will fetch automatic the latest (or multiple) data from the comment table.

Comment: I already used that feed mode, user model, comment model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our lengthy convo -

To save the feed_id (which is our foreign key for future relationships), you need to set/send the `feed_id` in your `POST` request. Laravel is not magic and won't know this automatically. You can do this by adding a hidden input, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="feed_id" value="{{ $feed->feed_id }}" />
```

In your `FeedController`, change your index to this:

```
public function index() {

  // $comments = Comment::latest()->get(); remove this
  // notice the "with" below. I'm eager loading in relations here
  $feeds = Feed::with('comments', 'user')->where('user_id', Sentinel::getUser()->id)->latest()->get(); 
  $blogs = Blog::latest()->simplePaginate(5);
  $blogs->setPath('blog');
  return view('action.index', compact('feeds', 'blogs'));
}
```

**Feed Model** should have the correct relationships, as below:

```
class Feed extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
     'feed_id',
     'user_id',
     'feed_content'
     ];

     public function user()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
     }

     public function comments()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'feed_id', 'feed_id');
     }
}
```

**Comment Model** should have the correct relationships, as below:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
     'comment',
     'user_id',
     'feed_id'
     ];

     public function feed()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Feed');
     }

     public function user()
     {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
     }
}
```

***Now you should be able to run your `foreach` as you currently have it.***

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I used your way also but showing error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comments(). When tried to did midification in $feeds section. Even the feed-id is not being stored.

Comment: "You're comment save method looks correct. If you put return $request->all() as the first line in that method, what does it return?"

Comment: "Also, in your Feed model, pluralize comment to `public function comments()` for better readability."

Comment: If I'm using return $request->all(); in first line of store comment method then it is returning this   {"_token":"Xw9qTEbg7VN2WA5ywDH8UE6q9UjQ5DmWoXVQb9kq","comment":"checking Comment"}         Checking comment is the comment which I wrote in comment section.

Comment: Okay...that explains it then. Where's the $request values you're trying to save? Where's `$request->feed_id` and `$request->comment`

Comment: So what modification should I do in order to get all the comments which belongs to the feeds.

Comment: What form is submitting to the `storecomment` method? One step at a time here. This method is wrong and hence why it's not saving. You're not passing any of the values you're trying to save.

Comment: In storecomment method comment form is being submitted and in database I've feed_id, comment and user_id table. In which I'm getting user_id and comment not  feed_id. This feed_id is same as feeds table feed_id.

Comment: Huh? You need to pass the `feed_id` when submitting the form dude. Right now, this doesn't exist: `$request->feed_id`. Show this form where someone enters a comment please.

Comment: But the thing is I want this thing to be done automatically with eloquent relationship or any other method because no user will know the feed_id of the feed. It should be connected in such a way that if any user comment on any feed then the feed_id of the feed will automatically be saved in comment feed_id and using the relationship we can display the comment which belongs to the feed

Comment: How is Laravel suppose to know the feed_id?!? It's not magic man lol. I don't think you truly understand how relationships work. You NEED to pass that value to the form request. Add a hidden input with name "feed_id"...make it's value the feed id, etc.

Comment: Can you tell me how to link the hidden input with value feed_id to the id of the feeds.

Comment: Oh man. If you haven't already, I'd look at watching some videos at Laracasts.com and brush up on basic HTML. `{{ Form::hidden('feed_id', $feed->id) }}` or standard way, `<input type="hidden" name="feed_id" val="{{ $feed->id }}" />`

Comment: What's happens when you return `$feeds` in your controller? Show me that result

Comment: And make sure the relationships are set up properly, as I stated

Comment: Thanks for replying and because of you only I'm able to save the feed_id. But I'm not able to show the comments though I have used the below code.

Comment: @foreach($feed->comments as $comment)
                    <div class="pull-left"> 
                        <img class="profile" src="{{ URL::to('/uploads/users/'. $comment->user->pic)  }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" style="width:48px;height:48px;padding-right : 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;">
                    </div>
                    {{ $comment->user->first_name }} 
                    {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}
                    {{ $comment->feed->comment }}<hr>
                @endforeach

Comment: In commentstore method if I'm writing $feeds = Feed::all(); and return $feeds, then it is returning all the feeds but if I'm writing only return $feeds then it is returning Undefined variable: feeds.

Comment: Of course you need to grab the feed first. Look at my answer. First code example man. You should also check out laracasts.com and go through the learners videos. It'll help. :)

Comment: Problems were running into now are entry level. Nevermind complex relationships. There's only so much I can do.

Comment: Thanks anyways for taking time and explaining the things which I didn't knew.

Comment: Return Feed::with('comments')->get();  tell me what that displays. Only one record. Not the whole object.

Comment: {"feed_id":47,"user_id":1,"feed_content":"now the feed_id is saved ","created_at":"2016-07-12 19:27:52","updated_at":"2016-07-12 19:27:52","comments":[]}

Comment: Okay. Perfect. I see comments appears in the array. Relationship is just about set. Now in Feed model, in the comments method change it to this `return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'feed_id', 'feed_id');`

Comment: [{"feed_id":55,"user_id":1,"feed_content":"First status","created_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:10","updated_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:10","comments":[{"id":82,"feed_id":55,"comment":"first comment","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:18","updated_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:18","deleted_at":null},{"id":84,"feed_id":55,"comment":"f1s2","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-07-13 07:32:42","updated_at":"2016-07-13 07:32:42","deleted_at":null}]}  Now it is returning the comments also.

Comment: Works! Right? Comments are there

Comment: Ya, but the thing is it is returning in json format and when I'm returning at my home page(where feeds and comments are suppose to be displayed) there it is showing error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.comment_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`comment_id` = 83 and `users`.`comment_id` is not null limit 1)

Comment: It's not returning json. It's returning an object. Remove all the users lines of code in the foreach. It'll work. Your relationship for users is wrong. Take what you learned here to set the user relationship up.

Comment: Hint, in your comment model, in user method, try this `return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id', 'id'); }`

Comment: When it works, please accept answer AND vote up please!

Comment: Even after changing the relationship of user as you told it is showing error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`user_id` = 83 and `users`.`user_id` is not null limit 1).

Comment: This is the for loop whic I'm using to show the comments @foreach($feed->comments as $comment) <div class="pull-left"> <img class="profile" src="{{ URL::to('/uploads/users/'. $comment->user->pic)  }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" style="width:48px;height:48px;padding-right : 10px;padding-bottom: 5px;"> </div> {{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }} {{ $comment->feed->comment }}<hr> @endforeach

Comment: In the `hasOne` which around "user_is" and "id". Put "id" first.

Comment: After replacing the position of 'user_id' and 'id'. It is showing this SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.feed_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`feed_id` = 1 and `users`.`feed_id` is not null limit 1)

Comment: Not sure why it's giving you that error. Are you in the Comment model? Sounds like you're in the Feed model...

Comment: No I'm in comment model only. See this are the codes feed.blade.php http://laravel.io/bin/Lk0Yl . feedscontroller:- http://laravel.io/bin/wJzjQ  user.php:- http://laravel.io/bin/qQPVW   feed.php:- http://laravel.io/bin/0ev19   comment.php:- http://laravel.io/bin/7wv0v  .  Please do look the codes I know its frustrating for you to see all the codes again but thank you for helping.

Comment: Well, does your Feed have a relationship to User? You're calling $feed->user, etc.

Comment: Also, on your Feed table, you should have an incrementing ID column...if "feed_id" is it, bad practice. Change to "id".

Comment: Yes Feed have a relationship with user. If I'm removing the comment loop from feed.blade.php then it is showing the feeds only with user name and with comment loop it is showing error but when I'm changing the relationship as you told in Feed then with or without comment loop it is showing error. And sorry I'm new to this coding n all so I changed that for better understanding of myself.

Comment: Right now after changing the relationship it is showing this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.feed_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`feed_id` is null and `users`.`feed_id` is not null)

Comment: ^ it's going to cause problems in the future and make your life a living hell...don't create bad habits. Trust. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll keep in my mind. So what should we do to remove this error.

Comment: Showing error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`user_id` is null and `users`.`user_id` is not null) with both the code which you told me to change

Comment: Error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`user_id` is null and `users`.`user_id` is not null)

Comment: Brain is pulsating lol I had an error, try this: `user() { return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'user_id'); }`

Comment: I've used user() { return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id', 'user_id'); } and user() { return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_id', 'id'); } both showing the above errors

Comment: Also, add "user" to `with`. Like so,  `$feeds = Feed::with('comments', 'user')->get();` For testing purposes, just `return $feeds;` in your controller until we get the user object for feed.

Comment: After changing from hasMany to hasOne then also it is showing error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`user_id` = 83 and `users`.`user_id` is not null limit 1). Even interchanging the 'user_id' and 'id'

Comment: Leave as `hasOne`. Tell me what `return $feeds;` returns when you add "user" to `with`. See my comment above.

Comment: Just looking at your controller method...mess...explains why some things are not working. I need to re-write the index. You didn't follow my code in answer. http://laravel.io/bin/fork/wJzjQ

Comment: To test, in FeedsController (index method) replace `return view('action.index', compact('feeds', 'blogs'));` with `return $feeds` so we can see result.

Comment: It is returning the object now.

Comment: {"feed_id":55,"user_id":1,"feed_content":"First status","created_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:10","updated_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:10","comments":[{"id":82,"feed_id":55,"comment":"first comment","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:18","updated_at":"2016-07-13 07:31:18","deleted_at":null},{"id":84,"feed_id":55,"comment":"f1s2","user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-07-13 07:32:42","updated_at":"2016-07-13 07:32:42","deleted_at":null}]

Comment: "user":{"id":1,"email":"admin@admin.com","permissions":[],"last_login":"2016-07-13 18:09:51","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","created_at":"2016-06-13 05:55:08","updated_at":"2016-07-13 18:09:51","deleted_at":null,"bio":null,"gender":null,"dob":"0000-00-00","pic":"11zsHvWsNQ.jpg","country":"","state":"","city":"","address":"","postal":"","username":"admin"}}].. It is returning everything like feed, comment and whatever is there in user table

Comment: Perfect. So now you foreach in your view should work, right?

Comment: Ok by seeing the result I guess it should be working. But how to show this in my home page.

Comment: Make sure `return $feeds` is obviously changed back to `return view('action.index', compact('feeds', 'blogs'));`. This was just to make sure the object was correct...

Comment: The object are returning fine but if I'm changing return $feeds to return view('action.index', compact('feeds', 'blogs')); it is showing error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`user_id` = 83 and `users`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)

Comment: This is all it is showing ErrorException in Connection.php line 662:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `users`.`user_id` = 83 and `users`.`user_id` is not null limit 1) (View: C:\wamp\www\newjosh\resources\views\action\partials\feed.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\newjosh\resources\views\action\partials\feed.blade.php)

Comment: Please Laravel Bin your current files: controller, feeds view, comment model, feed model. Thanks.

Comment: Feed model http://laravel.io/bin/QNMRd  feedcontroller http://laravel.io/bin/6LKOV  comment model http://laravel.io/bin/XyMRy  feed balde http://laravel.io/bin/NkeRV

Comment: After changing comment model getting this error ErrorException in Connection.php line 662:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'feeds.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `feeds` where `feeds`.`id` = 56 limit 1) (View: C:\wamp\www\newjosh\resources\views\action\partials\feed.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\newjosh\resources\views\action\partials\feed.blade.php)

Comment: Oh, you don't have a `id` column in your feeds table, right?

Comment: No instead of that I have feed_id

Comment: What's this in your view? `{{ $comment->feed->comment }}`? Remove this and see if the error still exists. This doesn't make sense to me. I think it should be `{{ $comment->comment }}`

Comment: Thank you for all this. You really are a saviour.

Comment: Now getting the output perfectly.

Comment: Phew!! Finally!!! haha. Please accept answer and give it an up vote if you can too - for the extra hard work. :p

Comment: I'd spend a week going through Laracasts.com too...super helpful and will save you lots of time long term. Jefferey Way is a great teacher.

Comment: Definitely I'll give up vote for your hard work. Can you tell me what was the mistakes I did so that I'll try not to repeat them.

Comment: No idea where to start with that. Just learn "relationships" and "eager loading" (i.e. the `with('comments', 'user')` stuff).

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. Any recommendation from where I should learn this and all.

Comment: Learn from Laracasts.com. By far best tutorials (all video) to learn Laravel. Thanks for the answer accept...if you could vote up as well, I'd be grateful!

Comment: I tried to up vote but it is saying that since I'm new user and have reputation less that 15 so they will record the up vote but they will not display in public.

Comment: No worries! As for tutorial, try this one: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch

Comment: Thanks for all this help. If you don't mind can I ask you one more thing.

Comment: Right now my home page is working fine not to mention all because of you. In my home page feeds and blogs are showing but not according to the created time. First it is loading all the feeds then it is loading the blogs. I want the mixture of all according to time not like first feed and then blog. I have echoed like this only http://laravel.io/bin/ro48Q because of that it is showing like this. So can you tell me how to correct that.

Comment: Hmm, that's a little more complex. I'd suggest making another question.

Comment: When/if you create a new question, post link here and I'll try and take a look.

Comment: Right now only I'll post within 15 mins

Comment: This is the link:-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361471/displaying-feeds-and-blogs-according-to-the-created-time