# How to get the feeds of the user whom you are following

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to get the feeds of the user whom you are following. Right now I'm able to get the id of the user whom you are following but struggling to get the feeds of the following user. **Followscontroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Redirect;
use App\User;
use Laracasts\Commander\CommanderTrait;
use App\FollowUserCommand; 
use Sentinel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class FollowsController extends Controller
{
use CommanderTrait;
/**
 * Follow a User
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = array_add(Input::all(), 'user_id', Sentinel::getuser()->id);
    $this->execute(FollowUserCommand::class, $input);
    return Redirect::back();
}


/**
 * Unfollow a User
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

**FollowUserCommand**

```
<?php namespace App;
use App\User;

class FollowUserCommand {

public $user_id;
public $userIdToFollow;

function __construct($user_id, $userIdToFollow)
{
    $this->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->userIdToFollow = $userIdToFollow;
}
}
```

**FollowUserCommandHandler**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Laracasts\Commander\CommandHandler;

class FollowUserCommandHandler implements CommandHandler {

protected $userRepo;

function __construct(UserRepository $userRepo)
{
    $this->userRepo = $userRepo;
}




public function handle($command)
{
    $user = $this->userRepo->findById($command->user_id);

    $this->userRepo->follow($command->userIdToFollow, $user);

    return $user;
}

}
```

**UserRepository**

```
<?php namespace App;
 use App\User;

class UserRepository {

public function save(User $user) 
{
    return $user->save();
}

public function getPaginated($howMany = 4)
{
    return User::orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->paginate($howMany);
}

public function findByUsername($username)
{
    return User::with(['feeds' => function($query)
    {
        $query->latest();
    }

    ])->whereUsername($username)->first();
}

public function findById($id) 
{
    return User::findOrFail($id);
}

public function follow($userIdToFollow, User $user)
{
    return $user->follows()->attach($userIdToFollow);
}
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php namespace App;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


 class User extends EloquentUser {


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes to be fillable from the model.
 *
 * A dirty hack to allow fields to be fillable by calling empty fillable array
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [];
protected $guarded = ['id'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

/**
* To allow soft deletes
*/
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



 public function feeds() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Feed');
}

public function comment()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
 }


    // This function allows us to get a list of users following us
public function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'follows', 'follower_id', 'followed_id')->withTimestamps();
}

// Get all users we are following
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follow_id')->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly straightforward.

```
$user = User::with('following.feeds')->get();
foreach ($user->following as $followedUser) {
    foreach ($followedUser->feeds as $feed) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using sub query I am able to get like below. if some one needs other way, check the following code

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', function($query) use($id)
        {
          $query->select('leader_id')
                ->from('followers')
                ->where('follower_id', $id);
        })->orWhere('user_id', $id)->latest()->paginate(10);
```